# To or Towards...?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Can 'to' be replaced with/used interchangeably with 'towards' in an essay to make myself sound more sophisticated or are there linguistical complications associated with using it everywhere? If so, what would be an example of an exception where only to can be used and not towards? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not going toward the trouble toward answer this. There must be some answer toward it, but toward my recollection, i've never seen it.

Comment: Just as a general rule, if you are (linguistically speaking) sophisticated, you can sound sophisticated simply by being yourself; but if you aren't sophisticated in this way, trying to sound as though you are is a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 3):

going to the river - the destination is definitely the river.
going towards the river - moving towards river but unsure whether river is the last destination or another place near the river.

Answer (score 1):

***To and toward(s)*** cannot be used interchangeably as explained in the following [extract](http://www.eslcafe.com/grammar/prepositions07.html):

> - The preposition to is another common preposition
>     of place. It is normally used with a verb showing
>     movement and shows the result of the movement--
>     the place or person that the movement was toward
>     or in the direction of. The preposition toward
>     has a similar meaning, but it's not exactly the same:
>     with toward, the direction of the movement is
>     shown, but not the result.
>
> A <====== to ====== B
>    (B arrived at A)
>
> A <==== toward ==== B
>   (B is on the way to A)
>
> A ====== to ======> B
>   (A arrived at B)
>
> A ==== toward ====> B
>   (A is on the way to B)
>
> Examples:
>
> Jamil walks to work every day.
>
> When I saw Jamil, he was walking toward his office.
>
> They'll drive to San Francisco during the weekend.
>
> They started driving toward San Francisco Friday
>   afternoon, but they didn't arrive there until Saturday.
>
> Yesterday Billy rode his bicycle to the park.
>
> When Billy was riding his bicycle toward the park,
>   he stopped at Joey's house.

---

> Special Note:
>
> ***To is actually more general than toward and can
>   be used instead of toward. Toward cannot be
>   used instead of to, however***:
>
> same:
>
> When I saw Jamil, he was walking toward
>   his office. / When I saw Jamil he was walking
>   to his office
>
> different:
>
> Jamil walks to work every day. / Jamil walks 
>   toward work every day.
>
> same:
>
> When Billy was riding his bicycle toward the park,
>   he stopped at Joey's house. / When Billy was riding
>   his bicycle to the park, he stopped at Joey's house.
>
> different:
>
> Yesterday Bilyl rode his bicycle to the park. /
>   Yesterday Billy rode his bicycle toward the park.

(www.eslcafe.com/grammar)

Answer (score 0):

to and towards are the very different terms. see-

Towards- is used for a particular direction for instance- 1/ you go towards your school. ( not sure whether or you arrived at school)
 To- using to is a bit different term than towards, it shows surety that you've made it to school or you will make it to school.
 so technically you may not use them interchangeably.